# Why can't I connect to an API when I generate the APK?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem with a login that I am doing, in my emulator it works correctly but when I generate the apk and test it on the phone, the API does not work.

I already assigned the Internet permission in the .xml and made tests to use Internet images and everything fine, so I discarded the permissions.

I do not know if it gives me an error because I use an http and not an https, or if someone has an idea of ​​what is happening here they tell me, I attach my code

Code:

```
void _login(BuildContext context) async {
if (!_loading) {
setState(() {
_loading = true;
});
}

//print(_username.value.text);
//print(_password.value.text);
var url = Uri.parse(
    "http://taquillamedicina.mdgsystem.com/index.php?route=api/loginapp");
String var1 = 'vipmedico';
String var2 =
    'xxxxx';
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  'username': var1,
  'password': var2,
  'usernameapp': _username.value.text,
  'passwordapp': _password.value.text
};
var jsonResponse = null;
var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
//print(response);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  // print(jsonResponse);
  if (jsonResponse != null) {
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
    sharedPreferences.setString("client_id", jsonResponse['client_id']);
    if (jsonResponse['error'] == '1') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/list");
    }
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    _loading = false;
  });
  print(response.body);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please *not* transfer usernames and passwords over unprotected HTTP? Kindly let know whoever is in charge that their security is broken (fix the Let's Encrypt certificate and disable HTTP). Anyway, new versions of Android [forbid cleartext traffic](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted) by default, so yes, using HTTP as opposed to HTTPS may be the problem.

Comment: do you remember to add `internet permission` ...  :)

Answer (score 0):

To get over this, you will have add  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.XML` file. But as advised, this isn't solving th eproblem, it's sweeping it under the carpet, but will get your task done for now.

Answer (score 0):

After I upgrade the Flutter 2.0 my app is down and I add  under Anroid>Src>Main>`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

API and app is worked